# Tetris clone in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a representation for each [initial shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris#Colors_of_tetrominoes) as an `Enum` with points and another for each rotated shape in the same `Enum`.

Here is an example of the latter `Enum`:

```
// 
//     * *
//     *
//     * 
J_SHAPE_SOUTH(new Point[] {
        new Point(2, 0),
        new Point(2, 1),
        new Point(2, 2),
        new Point(3, 2)
}),

// 
//   * *  
//     *  
//     *  
L_SHAPE_SOUTH(new Point[] {
        new Point(1, 2),
        new Point(2, 0),
        new Point(2, 1),
        new Point(2, 2)
});
```

I was then wondering whether to move the rotated shapes into individual `Enum`s, say `RotatedJShape`, or simply keep *all* the rotated shapes in the same `Enu`m. My concern is that some shapes like the I-shape only has one rotated condition, so it seems pointless to have an `Enum` for that shape.

What would be the most suitable approach in my case in terms of scalability and code correctness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ages ago I did a Tetris clone, and my idea for a data structure was this:

A circular linked list of matrices.

How do you rotate?  Walk the list...

You can have a single array of these lists (one per each block type), and your game logic's notion of the "current piece" is a reference to something inside that table.  That way the game logic can have no knowledge of the different shapes, and you declare a small array that defines what the shapes are.

Answer (score 5):

How are you rotating them now? Would it make more sense to change from an enum to a class with a Rotate method instead?

Comment: Swapping through the list of rotated pieces. I wanted an easy approach, that's why I did it this way. Rotating would require a somewhat complex logic.

Comment: @Whirlwin: I believe 'complex' is somewhat exaggerating. :) Besides you asked for a scalable approach. If you ever want to support other blocks, this is the most scalable.

Answer (score 2):

Have an enum like you do for the pieces.

That is okay.

Points is more work than you need to do.

The piece in play is an instance, with a reference to the original enum.

```
class FallingBlock {
    BlockEnum originalBlock;
    Point location;
    Shape shapeToDraw; // a copy of the original shape so you can manipulate it.
}
```

The shape instance can be rotated, scaled etc.. Java2D is quite helpful.
You could do it all with AffineTransforms upon original shapes , and not have an original shape and a copy but this way is less complicated.
And you can have arbitrarily complicated shapes!
You keep the original for the points value, and so you can display it in a "current block" pane.